# Breadth first iteration?

Tags: algorithm, search, iteration

If we wish to cover a search space, like say for all triplets `(x, y, z)`, where `x`, `y`, and `z` are between `1` and `n`, we can use nested looping to do this:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
   for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++)
      for (int z = 1; z <= n; z++)
```

This generates triplets: `(1, 1, 1)`, `(1, 1, 2)`, `(1, 1, 3)`, `(1, 1, 4)`, etc..., and is effectively a "depth first search" or depth first iteration.

Is there a way to iterate in a more "breadth first" fashion? Such an iteration would generate triplets in an order similar to:

`(1, 1, 1)`, `(2, 1, 1)`, `(1, 2, 1)`, `(1, 1, 2)`, `(2, 2, 1)`, `(2, 1, 2)`, `(1, 2, 2)`, `(2, 2, 2)`, `(3, 1, 1)`, etc...

and is there also a name for the algorithm that would generate such a pattern?

Comment: I recommend just using an actual breadth-first search. Start with `(1, 1, 1)`, and whenever you dequeue `(x, y, z)`, enqueue each of `(x+1, y, z)`, `(x, y+1, z)`, and `(x, y, z+1)` that hasn't already been enqueued and doesn't go past the bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C# code generates the pattern I described, and in a good order, but I have a feeling there is a better way to do it.

```csh
void Visit(ISet<Tuple<int, int, int>> pSet, int pX, int pY, int pZ) {
   var value = Tuple.Create(pX, pY, pZ);
   if (pSet == null)
      Console.WriteLine(value);
   else if (!pSet.Contains(value)){
      pSet.Add(value);
      Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
}

void Iterate() {
   const int n = 5;
   for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
      var set = new HashSet<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
      for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++)
         for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
            Visit(set, z, y, x);
            Visit(set, z, x, y);
            Visit(set, y, z, x);
            Visit(set, y, x, z);
            Visit(set, x, z, y);
            Visit(set, x, y, z);
         }
   }
}
```

This code generates the pattern without maintaining any lists or doing any collision checking. I've confirmed that it generates n³ tuples with no duplicates (up to n=500). The only issue is that this only works for the specific case of iterating over 3-tuples of ints, rather than any number of any type of collections.

```csh
static void Iterate() {
   const int n = 500;
   for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
      for (int y = 1; y <= x; y++)
         for (int z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
            Visit(z, y, x);
            if (x == y && y == z && x == z)
               continue;

            if (x != y)
               Visit(z, x, y);

            if (z != y) {
               Visit(y, z, x);
               Visit(y, x, z);
            }

            if (x != y && x != z) {
               Visit(x, z, y);
               if (z != y)
                  Visit(x, y, z);
            }
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
This should work.  
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
           for (int y = 1; y <= n; y++)
              {
               for (int z = 1; z <= n; z++)
                {  
                  enqueue(the x-y-z triplet);
                }
                  print(till the queue empties);
                }
Sorry for my pseudo-C.
```

Comment: the queue isn't doing anything. this is identical to the "depth first" iteration of just three nested loops.